# Why rendered video ends before its duration?

Tags: animation, interface, video-sequence-editor, effects

I have 60 min screencast from my desktop.
I want to speed up it so it fit in 5 min
I have selected strip > **Add > Effect strip > Speed control**
**Scaled strip size so it fits within 5 min**(with speed control strip)
Most of scene settings set default. Just changed resolution, format (FFmpegVideo) encoding to H.264.
Hit Render animation. It renders all frames.
HOWEVER, when i open final result all video fit in ~1.5 - 2 minutes, and all after that just nothing, while player timeline shows that length of video is 5 minutes. Player just stop because seems like it know that video should 5 min but frames ended earlier.
Feels like some fps settings must be changed but how to do it correctly?

What am I forgetting.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you cut the video before changing its speed?

Comment: If you're using the latest blender version, it has bugs in speed strip: https://developer.blender.org/T89120 try opening your project in an earlier version of Blender.

Comment: @zargulthewizard , No, why should i? I want fit 60 min into 5 min(no audio provided) just it. Problem is that after render player see video length as 5 min(as in blender timeline) but video itself ends earlier

Comment: Just checking. I’ve had trouble with speed control before.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that VLC player does not handle well MP4 rendered by blender with h.264 and it's just issue with it.
I edit message when/if get more details